# Get the data result with the spaces between columns from XML using Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

I expect the data to be returned as `basics 10`, due to the space between title tag and price tag, but instead, I am getting `basics10` when using extract function in Oracle query.

When I am using the following query:

```
SELECT Extract(column_nam,'//text()').getStringVal() FROM dual;
```

Against the XML like below:

```
 <Publishers>
   <publish>     
     <title>basics</title> 
     <price>10</price> 
   </publish>
 </Publishers>
```

When I am using extract function in my query it is eliminating all the spaces. can some one please suggest on the same.

Thank you ...

Comment: Please edit your question to fix the formatting. The spaces in your XML are between the elements, not part of the actual content (text). Do you really want each text value as a seperate column in your result set, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

According to your provided XML, I prepared this `demo` code:

```
  WITH demo AS (
   SELECT XMLTYPE (
     '<Publishers>
       <publish>     
         <title>basics</title> 
         <price>10</price> 
       </publish>
     </Publishers>') XML
   FROM dual)
    SELECT XML.title || ' ' || XML.price
    FROM demo dm,
         xmltable('/Publishers/publish' passing dm.XML
                    COLUMNS  title VARCHAR2(50) path 'title',
                             price VARCHAR2(4) path 'price') XML;
```

Here I separated your data from XML onto two columns and then just `SELECT` by concatenation function from the `XMLTYPE table`;

And now `Result` with `white space` between two columns: `basics 10`;

From `Oracle 10.2` you can use `XMLTABLE` operator, which allows you to project columns on to XML data in an XMLTYPE, making it possible to query the data directly from SQL as if it were relational data.

Useful: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/xmltable-convert-xml-data-into-rows-and-columns-using-sql

Comment: Thank you for your response, Sorry i did not mention the question clearly. actually my problem is i just sent the sample XML, but my XML is going to be very big and i need to pull the data only from specifictag. this xml is not going to be static for every item, it is going to change, the tags inside is going to change also. I am attaching sample XML here:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item> <item_information number="sdjsadh" > <response_direction delivery_mode="xcs"> <direction_paragraph>test</direction_paragraph> </response_direction> </item_information> <item_content> <stimulus_reference> <passage> <prose style="1"> <passage_para>   <expression> <math xmlns="Math" xmlns:xlink="xlink" display="inline" overflow="scroll"> <mr> <mi>z</mi> <mo>&gt;</mo> <mn>0</mn> </mr> </math> </expression> </passage_para> </prose> </passage> </stimulus_reference>  </item_content>    </item>

Comment: i want to read the data from passage_para tag ,after passage para i have 2 spaces before expression and after expression tag i have one more space..etc.., when i used extract query to get passage_para tag from the XMLTYPE column it is eliminating all the spaces. and giving the below output: <passage_para><expression><math xmlns="Math" xmlns:xlink="xlink" display="inline" overflow="scroll"><mr><mi>z</mi><mo>&gt;</mo><mn>0</mn </mr></math></expression></passage_para> which i dont want because it is taking out the spaces. the desired out put is "     z  > 0    "

Comment: the XML tags may change in passage_para tag..XML is not static..apperciate your help on this...

Comment: @Saritha - [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45578722/edit) to include all of those clarificatins. Also explain, if tags may change how do you know which tags' text you want, and in what order?

Comment: I think it's better to create a new `Post` with a good explanation of the problem.

Comment: i hvae created one more post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45623078/how-to-read-the-data-from-xml-with-spaces-using-oracle