# how to read the data from XML with spaces using oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to read the data from `passage_para` tag, after `passage_para` I have 2 spaces before the `expression` tag and after the `expression` tag I have one more space, etc. When I use `extract` function to get the `passage_para` tag from the `XMLTYPE` column it is eliminating all the spaces.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <item> <information number="sdjsadh" > <response_direction delivery_mode="xcs"> <dparagraph>test</dparagraph> </response_direction> </information> <i_content> <stimulus_reference> <passage> <prose style="1"> <passage_para> <expression> <math xmlns="Math" xmlns:xlink="xlink" display="inline" overflow="scroll"> <mr> <mi>z</mi> <mo>&gt;</mo> <mn>0</mn> </mr> </math> </expression> </passage_para> </prose> </passage> </stimulus_reference> </i_content> </item>
```

which I don't want because it is taking out the spaces. The desired output I need is `" z > 0 "`.

*Note:* Between the `passage_para` tag the child nodes may change, they are not going to be the same.

Comment: You are mistaken. That's not how the data is stored in XML. Spaces between two different tags are immaterial.